# Cause vs Causes

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about this sentence:

Because the longer it lasts, the more problems it may causes

Psdt: I am writing about Bullying

is it right the last part? Thank you:=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Cause" is the correct form, rather than "causes," as it is currently written.
The "may" (indicating the subjunctive, or hypothetical, mood) is what shifts this, as the sentence "Because the longer it lasts, the more problems it causes" is grammatically correct in regards to your question, but when the sentence is dealing with a hypothetical situation you need to change it to "cause."

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Please don't give 'answers' to questions patently too basic for a site aimed at linguists. Please look at other well-upvoted questions, especially on grammar, to get a feel for the intended level of questions.